# Android makefile: build all sources in a directory tree instead of listing files one by one

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface

I'm porting an iPhone game (c++) to Android and I'm just getting started with this.

In the Android.mk file I have to list all the source files that need to be built, something like this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := importgl.c demo.c etc.c
```

The game I'm porting consists of hundreds of .cpp files, is there any way to include all the sources in a directory tree?

**EDIT:** Maybe is there any way to make eclipse update the makefile automatically?

Answer (score 0):

What's about using [`wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function)?

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
```